# Support of $H^1$ functions in higher dimensions

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

Let $u \in H^1(\Omega)$, where $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^d$, for $d \geq 2$. In particular, $H^1$ does not embed into the continuous functions. I was wondering if it is known how pathological the support of $u$ can get. In particular, is it possible for $u$ to be supported on a set of positive Lebesgue measure which does not contain any open set (for instance something like $C\times C$, where $C$ is the fat cantor set)?

Comment: Yes: there even exist smooth compactly supported functions on such sets, as long as the set is closed (which a product of fat cantor sets is).

Comment: Well but surely if $u$ is continuous, then by continuity $u^{-1}(\mathbb{R}\setminus \{0\})$ is open. Since this is a subset of the support of $u$, it shows that $C\times C$ contains an open set, which is false.

Comment: You are right, I was thinking of how you can construct a smooth compactly supported function whose zero set is any closed set.

Comment: No worries, thanks!